# PHP how to get mysql username and password from mysql_connect()

Tags: php

is there any way to get `host` , `username` and `password` from `mysql_connet("localhost","abc","***")` .  For some other reason i don't want to assign variable for password.

Comment: please clear yourself a bit.

Comment: You have them right there in `mysql_connet("localhost","abc","***")` except the host/user/pass here is an example. Once you have *made* the connection, there is no way to get the details back out - short of using the same variables again, or simply manually using a string. Being able to do so would be a security hole don't you think?

Comment: why you don't want to assign password using variable ?

Comment: @user3745183: This is probably the most valuable password of the whole application. Having it just laying around in plaintext is very much insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to get back host / username / password, once you have made connection. if you don't want to assign password by using variable use **mysql.default_password** string which is use when connecting to the database server if no other password is specified. specified in php.ini file.

**Warning:** any user with read access to php.ini file can reveal the password.

Comment: so send me how can i set default password i am beginner to PHP

Answer (score 2):

> For some other reason i don't want to assign variable for password.

You can use the INI settings `mysql.default_user` and `mysql.default_password`. See [this manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php).